# '--gc-sections' flag for XCode linker

Tags: ios, linker, xcode5, footprint

I'm trying to reduce footprint of a mobile application. For android I've used `--gc-sections` linker flag and it reduced about 20% of the `.so` file. But, this flag is not recognized by xcode linker (`unsupported option '--gc-sections'`). Is there an equivalent flag for xcode linker or maybe I'm using it wrong? Thanks!